# Simplifying a certain bound

Tags: real-analysis

I have the bound $$f(x)\leq C\epsilon^{-i/2}(1+Ce^{-x/\sqrt{\epsilon}})$$ for some quantity $f$ and $\epsilon$ is small. If $x\leq2$ and assuming that $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}>2.$$ How can I show that $$f(x)\leq C\epsilon^{-i/2}e^{-x/\sqrt{\epsilon}}$$

Comment: Is $i$ some natural number and $C>0$?

Answer (score 2):

**edit:** I am assuming $C>0$.

---

This does not hold in general. Your first inequality implies the second one if and only if
$$1+Ce^{-x/\sqrt{\varepsilon}} \leq e^{-x/\sqrt{\varepsilon}}$$
holds. This is the case iff
$$e^{x/\sqrt{\varepsilon}} + C \leq 1.$$
Using $x \leq 2$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}} > 2$ yields
$$e^{x/\sqrt{\varepsilon}} < e,$$
so for your implication to hold you would need $e + C \leq 1$.